# Running a macro from a another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace on the line `Application.Run "c:\users\navin\test\"` with `path` but it won't work. (Error 1004).

```
Sub test()
Dim path As String
path = "c:\users\navin\test\"

Workbooks.Open (path & "excel.xlsb")

Application.Run "'c:\users\navin\test\new.xlsb!macro1'"
Workbooks("excel.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Navin,
I don't really understand your question, could you please clarify it more.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you open a workbook called `excel.xlsb` and then attempt to run a macro in a workbook called `new.xslb`. You also have two sets of quotes, which is likely to cause problems.

Where you attempt to run the macro, you should reference only the name of the workbook.

`Application.Run "excel.xlsb!macro1"`